# Image will not display but is uploaded to server ok

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I am wanting to use an upload facility to allow users to upload a profile picture. The uploading part is working perfectly... However, when I try and display the image uploaded below, it appears as a broken image. I have tried lots of different sample code from questions already here, and I'm getting the same problem over and over. Any help would be appreciated! Apologies if my formatting is rubbish... I'm pretty new

Here is my upload.php

```
<?php require 'config/init.php';
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
 else
  {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

   if     
(file_exists("/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
   else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br>";

$image = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
$img = "/images/".$image;
echo "<img src=\"/images/$img\">";
  }
  }
 }
else
{
  echo "Invalid file";
}


?>
```

Here is my html form

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
 <br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Is the image on server not corrupt ? (try to display it) do you have the right access to allow a public display of your image ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'broken image'? Does server return anything?

Comment: @AdamLesniak it returns for example 'Uploaded file: leedsnew.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 72.265625 kilobytes' but then below where the image should be, it comes up as if it cannot find the image i.e. blank image with broken in half

Comment: @Blag I assume so as the image appears in the folder when uploaded?

Comment: When you're looking at this upload page, what URL is in your web browser's address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hamish pointed out in the other answer, you are confusing local file paths with remote URLs. While PHP is fine working with the files on your hard drive, you obviously don't want to expose that to the outside world. So you rely on Apache to convert *certain* file paths into URLs. Based on your comments above, I think this should do the trick. Note the placeholder variables for the local file path (`$file_location`) versus the URL (`$image_url`.)

```
<?php
require 'config/init.php';
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000000000000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        $local_file = "/customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk//httpd.www/AIDAc3410801/assets/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $image_url = "/AIDAc3410801/assets/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        if (file_exists($local_file)) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $local_file);
            echo "Stored in: " . $local_file ."<br>";
            echo "<img src=\"$image_url\">";
        }
    }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes! It works!! Thank you! Do you know how I could save this to a specific user and allow this to display every time they log in? @miken32

Comment: Presumably you have your users stored in a database, just add a field to store the image file name. Try some things out and post another question if you run into troubles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it! @miken32

Answer (score 1):

You're echoing an HTML tag image tag like so:

```
<img src="/customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk//httpd.www/AIDAc3410801/assets/images/SOME_IMAGE.JPG">
```

That this isn't a valid web address for client browsers. You need to return the URL that is valid for that image, as served by your server.

EDIT: actually, it's much worse, since you define `$img` with the same path, then pre-pend it with the path *again*, so your URLs look something like:

```
<img src="/customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk//httpd.www/AIDAc3410801/assets/images//customers/2/e/e/jessicarosedavidson.co.uk//httpd.www/AIDAc3410801/assets/images/SOME_IMAG.JPG">
```

Check the output to the browser.

Comment: I have tried echo "<img src=\". $img .\">";     ...still not working? @Hamish

Comment: `$img` still has to be something the browser can access. Ie, a URL you can put into your browser to see the image (over the internet).